# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException even when field exists in class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to deserialize my JSON request string using `ObjectMapper` and getting `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "employeeSkillRoles" (class com.csiindia.entities.EmployeeResume)` but this property exists in my class definition.

I cannot use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` or `mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)` as I need this value in my class object. Tried assigning @JsonProperty("employeeSkills") annotation to class field and its getter/setter functions but still it does not work.

**JSON Request:**

```
{
    "employeeResumeId": {
        "empId": "0000110833"
    },
    "experience": "2.8",
    "travelOnsite": "true",
    "remark": "Shubham Jain: Resume Approval Application",
    "submittedTo": {
        "empId": "0000111445"
    },
        "employeeSkills": [
        { "employeeSkillsId": {
            "skillId": "1"
        },
        { "employeeSkillsId": {
            "skillId": "2"
        },
        { "employeeSkillsId": {
            "skillId": "3"
        },
        { "employeeSkillsId": {
            "skillId": "4"
        }
    ],
    "employeeSkillRoles": [
        { "employeeSkillRolesId": {
            "skillRoleId": "1"
        },
        { "employeeSkillRolesId": {
            "skillRoleId": "2"
        },
        { "employeeSkillRolesId": {
            "skillRoleId": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Entity Class EmployeeResume:**

```
public class EmployeeResume {

@EmbeddedId
private EmployeeResumeId employeeResumeId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId(value = "EMPID")
@JoinColumn(name = "EMPID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_RESUME_EMPLOYEE"))
private Employee employee;

@Column(name = "EXPERIENCE", columnDefinition = "decimal(4,2) default 0", nullable = false)
private Float experience;

@Column(name = "TRAVELONSITE", nullable = false)
private Boolean travelOnsite;

@Column(name = "REMARK", columnDefinition = "varchar(1024)", nullable = false)
private String remark;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SUBMITTEDTO", referencedColumnName = "EMPID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_RESUME_SUBMITTEDTO"), columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(16)")
private Employee submittedTo;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "empid", referencedColumnName = "empid"), @JoinColumn(name = "lastupdateddate", referencedColumnName = "lastupdateddate")})
@JsonBackReference(value = "employeeSkills")
@JsonProperty("employeeSkills")
private Set<EmployeeSkills> employeeSkills;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "empid", referencedColumnName = "empid"), @JoinColumn(name = "lastupdateddate", referencedColumnName = "lastupdateddate")})
@JsonBackReference(value = "employeeSkillRoles")
private Set<EmployeeSkillRoles> employeeSkillRoles;

public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}

public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}

public Float getExperience() {
    return experience;
}

public void setExperience(Float experience) {
    this.experience = experience;
}

public Boolean getTravelOnsite() {
    return travelOnsite;
}

public void setTravelOnsite(Boolean travelOnsite) {
    this.travelOnsite = travelOnsite;
}

public String getRemark() {
    return remark;
}

public void setRemark(String remark) {
    this.remark = remark;
}

public Employee getSubmittedTo() {
    return submittedTo;
}

public void setSubmittedTo(Employee submittedTo) {
    this.submittedTo = submittedTo;
}

public EmployeeResumeId getEmployeeResumeId() {
    return employeeResumeId;
}

public void setEmployeeResumeId(EmployeeResumeId employeeResumeId) {
    this.employeeResumeId = employeeResumeId;
}

@JsonProperty("employeeSkills")
public Set<EmployeeSkills> getEmployeeSkills() {
    return employeeSkills;
}

@JsonProperty("employeeSkills")
public void setEmployeeSkills(Set<EmployeeSkills> employeeSkills) {
    this.employeeSkills = employeeSkills;
}

public Set<EmployeeSkillRoles> getEmployeeSkillRoles() {
    return employeeSkillRoles;
}

public void setEmployeeSkillRoles(Set<EmployeeSkillRoles> employeeSkillRoles) {
    this.employeeSkillRoles = employeeSkillRoles;
}
}
```

**Entity Class EmployeeSkills:**

```
public class EmployeeSkills {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeSkillsId employeeSkillsId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId(value = "EMPID")
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_EMPSKILLS_EMPLOYEE"))
    private Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId(value = "SKILLID")
    @JoinColumn(name = "SKILLID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_EMPSKILLS_SKILLS"))
    private Skills skill;

    @Column(name = "SCORE", columnDefinition = "decimal(2,1) default 0")
    private Float score;

    public EmployeeSkillsId getEmployeeSkillsId() {
        return employeeSkillsId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeSkillsId(EmployeeSkillsId employeeSkillsId) {
        this.employeeSkillsId = employeeSkillsId;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public Skills getSkill() {
        return skill;
    }

    public void setSkill(Skills skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }

    public Float getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(Float score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

**Entity Class EmployeeSkillRoles:**

```
public class EmployeeSkillRoles {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeSkillRolesId employeeSkillRolesId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId(value = "EMPID")
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_EMPSKILLROLES_EMPLOYEE"))
    private Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId(value = "SKILLROLEID")
    @JoinColumn(name = "SKILLROLEID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_EMPSKILLROLES_SKILLROLES"))
    private SkillRoles skillRoles;

    public EmployeeSkillRolesId getEmpSkillRolesId() {
        return employeeSkillRolesId;
    }

    public void setEmpSkillRolesId(EmployeeSkillRolesId employeeSkillRolesId) {
        this.employeeSkillRolesId = employeeSkillRolesId;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public SkillRoles getSkillRoles() {
        return skillRoles;
    }

    public void setSkillRoles(SkillRoles skillRoles) {
        this.skillRoles = skillRoles;
    }

}
```

**StackTrace of Exception:**

```
2019-01-17 09:45:20.252 ERROR 16208 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "employeeSkillRoles" (class com.csiindia.entities.EmployeeResume), not marked as ignorable (10 known properties: "travelOnsite", "processingDate", "resumeUrl", "employeeResumeId", "experience", "employee", "remark", "status", "submittedTo", "processInstId"])
 at [Source: {
    "employeeResumeId": {
        "empId": "0000110833"
    },
    "experience": "2.8",
    "travelOnsite": "true",
    "remark": "Shubham Jain: Resume Approval Application",
    "submittedTo": {
        "empId": "0000111445"
    },
    "employeeSkillRoles": [
        { "employeeSkillRolesId": {
            "skillRoleId": "1"
        },
        { "employeeSkillRolesId": {
            "skillRoleId": "2"
        },
        { "employeeSkillRolesId": {
            "skillRoleId": "3"
        }
    ],
    "employeeSkills": [
        { "employeeSkillsId": {
            "skillId": "1"
        },
        { "employeeSkillsId": {
            "skillId": "2"
        },
        { "employeeSkillsId": {
            "skillId": "3"
        },
        { "employeeSkillsId": {
            "skillId": "4"
        }
    ]
}

    ; line: 11, column: 25] (through reference chain: com.csiindia.entities.EmployeeResume["employeeSkillRoles"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:834) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1093) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1489) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1467) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:282) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3814) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2858) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.csiindia.controller.EmpSkillsController.submitEmployeeResumeForApproval(EmpSkillsController.java:207) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.csiindia.controller.EmpSkillsController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6d777697.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at com.csiindia.controller.EmpSkillsController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e6c8787d.submitEmployeeResumeForApproval(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: `I cannot use @JsonIgnoreProperties or mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)` why? it will just ignore unknown and unspecified ones

Comment: @AvijitBarua Added class definitions, please check.

Comment: @Deadpool I need those values in my object after deserialization, so I cannot ignore those.

Comment: can you update this calls `EmployeeSkillRoles` and if also complete Error message with stack trace @ShubhamJain

Comment: @Deadpool Added complete stacktrace. Please check.

Comment: The error message is very clear, in `EmployeeResume` class you have  `Employee`property `private Employee employee;`, but in the JSON payload you don't have that, so while deserializing what do you want to set to that property? @ShubhamJain

Comment: @Deadpool Error is not because of `Employee` property. If the property is not present, it is set to `null` by default. Error is because of `employeeSkills` and `employeeSkillRoles` property which I am sending and are present in class definition also.

Comment: If you set `@JsonIgnoreProperties` then only it is going to set null for unknown or unrecognized properties, that classes might be the reason also because they also consists unknown properties, I will suggest try to understand `@JsonIgnoreProperties` it will not remove anything, it will just set null for unknown and unrecognized, add that and try

Comment: @ShubhamJain, First let me understand your requirements. `EmployeeResume` is a pojo class you created according to the JSON. And you wanted to bind JSON data to `EmployeeResume`. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Deadpool I did try `@JsonIgnoreProperties` and it did not give any exception. But the object contains `null` value for field `employeeSkills` and `employeeSkillRoles`. I need those field values for request processing, so cannot ignore and let them be set as `null`

Comment: any idea why are you using this `@JsonBackReference(value = "employeeSkills")`?

Comment: @Deadpool Thanks a lot. I just commented out `@JsonBackReference` from the fields and it worked perfectly fine. I was using it because whenever I query `EmployeeResume` object, I want `EmployeeSkills` and `EmployeeSkillRoles` values also to be fetched and sent back in `json` response to client. Any other way to do that since I removed the annotation now?

Comment: i have no idea on it @ShubhamJain

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this dependency:
    `<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
     <version>2.6.6</version>
     </dependency>`

and add 
    `import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
     @XmlElement(name = "EmployeeSkillRoles")
     private Set<EmployeeSkillRoles> employeeSkillRoles;`

Comment: UPD: @XmlElement(name = "employeeSkillRoles")